# Show an other customer orders to other one | Admin panel orders are correct against each customer but only in frontend it was not showing correct

Tags: magento, magento2

We faced one very strange issue. In which all customers were seeing other customers orders. I verified in admin panel orders are correct against each customer but only in frontend it was not showing correct. I also verified the database of customer orders there also customers have correct orders against customer id.

Please if you have faced this issue then please let me know.

Frontend

[image]

Backend

[image]

Note:

1: I have checked the related route sales layout files to verify whether it is cacheable false or not. It is cacheable false but still showing wrong orders at frontend.

2: When I flush the cache using command `php bin/magento cache:flush` then it shows correct at frontend but after a while again same issue occurred. Check the full page cache but it is working fine.

Thank You!

Abbas

Answer (score 0):

If you are also facing same issue then make sure varnish is not caching the dynamic routes such as cart, customer, and sales etc. In this case varnish was caching against route sales. Which is dynamic and should not be cached. I hope it will help you.

Thank You!

Abbas